# Getting a reponse from a web api in JSON format

Tags: c#, json, rest, api

I am new with `web service` and `API`'s and trying to get a response from a URL with a post method and passing a parameter to it. I am developing a C# winform application that sending request to this `api` and must return the output in JSON format. Below is my code so war i only getting an OK response instead of the actual JSON data.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string postData = "station=sub";
            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);



            Uri target = new Uri("http://apijsondata/tz_api/");
            WebRequest myReq = WebRequest.Create(target);

            myReq.Method = "POST";
            myReq.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            myReq.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

            using (var dataStream = myReq.GetRequestStream())
            {
                dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
            }

            using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)myReq.GetResponse())
            {
                //Do what you need to do with the response.
                MessageBox.Show(response.ToString());
            }


        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use a `StreamReader` together with [HttpWebResponse.GetResponseStream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httpwebresponse.getresponsestream?view=netframework-4.8)()

For example,

```
 var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
 var json = reader.ReadToEnd();
```